# ObjectinputStream objects in a jar

Tags: java

I'm trying to read an object from a jar file but my code fails, I have the following code:

```
try {
        for (String string : Files) {
            Object ob = null;
            if (jarFile.isFile()) {
                InputStream in = MainComponent.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("mario/Animazioni/enemy/boo/boo-stand.anim");
                ob = new ObjectInputStream(in);
            } else {
                ob = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(string)).readObject();
            }
            System.out.println(""+ob.getClass());
            if ((ob).getClass() == Cut.class) {
                list.add((Cut) ob);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Altro elemento");
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Memoria.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

I get the error java.ioexception mark / reset not supported, and within my object is loaded an ObjectInputStream class object, I do not know why I load that class because I'm reading a class file " Cut ".

Comment: Try `InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(MainComponent.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("mario/Animazioni/enemy/boo/boo-stand.anim"));` and I would also prefer `if (ob instanceof Cut)` over your current test.

Comment: GRAVE: null
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.getInIfOpen(Unknown Source) ...

Comment: Where is/are the stack trace(s) that should have accompanied this question?

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't begin to make sense. `ob` is either an instance of `ObjectInputStream` or whatever is returned by `ObjectInputStream.readObject()`. Make up your mind. The purpose of `ObjectInputStreams` is to *read objects* from them. Try using `ob.readObject()` in both arms of the `if/else`.